# TRY_CONVERT in CASE WHEN

Tags: sql-server

I have SQL code like this:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(int, strCol) IS NULL
    THEN strCol
    ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(int, strCol))
END
```

Table is as follow:

```
| strCol |
|--------|
| 000373 |
| 2AB38  |
| C2039  |
| ABC21  |
| 32BC   |
```

I wish to drop all the leading 0s in rows with pure number

```
| strCol |
|--------|
| 373 |
| 2AB38  |
| C2039  |
| ABC21  |
| 32BC   |
```

But I got the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2AB38' to data type int.

I don't quite understand, it should not even enter the second case branch isn't it?

---

Comment: There is no guarantee it will short circuit. Sometimes all branches are evaluated.

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Comment: @DaleK, seems thats the case, change the secondary branch to `TRY_CONVERT(VARCHAR, TRY_CONVERT(int, 'X0304'))` works

Comment: @Programnik I'm using SQL Server

Comment: In sql server there exists ISNUMERIC function, use that as a test with extra case selector in second branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you so much @Dale K and @Programnik

```
        CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(strCol) = 0
            THEN strCol
            ELSE TRY_CONVERT(VARCHAR, TRY_CONVERT(int, strCol))
        END AS strCol
```

These is the piece of code got the work done.

1. All branches are evaluated, there are no guarantee it will short circuit @Dale K
2. Can use ISNUMERIC in SQL SERVER @Programnik

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option is try_convert in concert with a coalesce

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([strCol] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('000373')
,('2AB38')
,('C2039')
,('ABC21')
,('32BC')
 
Select *
      ,NewVal = coalesce(left(try_convert(int,strCol),10),strCol)
 From @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
strCol  NewVal
000373  373
2AB38   2AB38
C2039   C2039
ABC21   ABC21
32BC    32BC
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @Dale K's answer:

> The data types of else_result_expression and any result_expression must be the same or must be an implicit conversion.

You can't only TRY_CONVERT to int, you have to convert back to VARCHAR. Therefore you could also use a TRY_CONVERT nested inside a simple CONVERT:

```
    CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(strCol) = 0
        THEN strCol
        ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR, TRY_CONVERT(int, strCol))
    END AS strCol
```

[Sql doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)